# Creating a large CSV file

Tags: .net

I am trying to create a CSV file by writing 20M rows out of a database. Is this feasible, I can go up to 1M rows and write it wihout a problem. But I am not sure what issues I will have when I get to 20M. Want to get your advice, before I even attempt it.

Answer (score 2):

You can read / write unlimited rows (given enough disk space), if you one keep one row in memory at a time.

I.e. read a row from Db, write that row to CSV file. Repeat.